# Count Number of Specific Value in SQL Table/Database (Flask)

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have a SQL database that contains 8 rows and 8 columns and I would like to count the number of values, i, as an integer, that the letter X appears in this database. The term 'rowvalues' is a separate column, and each of these is the first entry of a specific row. (so, technically, there are 11 columns). My code is right now as follows:

```
columnvalues = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8']
rowvalues = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
for i in columnvalues:
    for j in lettervalues:
        cfv = db.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablle['i'] WHERE Letter='X'")
        print(cfv)
```

Yet, this prints multiple tuplets. Can anyone help me out in how to do this simple command?

UPDATE: Can ANYONE on this website help me???

Comment: Tuples are the expected return value type when using the execute command. Simply slice your tuple to get the value you want.

Comment: @JonathanPorter What does that mean?